# Is there a faster way go compare two, unequal ranges in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

This take forever to execute.  Is there a faster way?

```
Function add_column_binary(sheet_name_from As String, col_from As Integer, sheet_to As String, col_to As Integer)

'   set range  - the range to be looped through to find key for searching the second range
    Dim first_range As Range

'   set ragen - the range in teh second sheet to be repeatedly searched
    Dim second_range As Range
    Set second_range = set_range(sheet_to, col_to)

'   find last column
    Dim last_col As Integer
    last_col = Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

'   label last column
    Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, last_col + 1).Value = "Invited = 1"

    Dim rows1 As Long
    rows1 = first_range.Cells(rows.Count, col_from).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' grab the length of the range on the first sheet

    Dim n As Long
    Dim constructed_id As String

    Dim find_result As Range
    For n = 2 To rows1
        constructed_id = "ObjectID(" & first_range.Cells(n, 1) & ")"  ' format object id
        Set find_result = second_range.Find(constructed_id, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not find_result Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(n, last_col + 1) = "1"
        Else
            Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(n, last_col + 1) = "0"
        End If
    Next n
    Stop

End Function


Sub test_stuff()

    Dim x As Range
      Set x = add_column_binary("invitesOutput.csv", 3, "usersFullOutput.csv", 1)
'    Debug.Print "x = " & x.Address
End Sub
```

The first range is over 8,000 cells and the second range is about 15,000 cells.

Comment: Do you have any repeated values in the first range? Either list sortable?

Comment: there are some repeats, but not a ton.

Comment: can you upload sample dataor sheet and i will try tinker with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually faster (between 10 and 100 times faster) to get the data into variant arrays and work on those rather than using Find.
See this blog post https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

If that is not fast enough you could look at using Dictionaries etc: see
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/comparing-two-lists-vba-udf-shootout-between-linear-search-binary-search-collection-and-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's pretty brute force-y. The only suggestion I would have is to [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) perhaps against the duplicates. Just store looked up values in an array and instead of searching 15,000 cells you can just look in your array first.

Maybe there is a way to scrub the input data first to structure it in a way that's more conducive to searching? Sometimes you can eat a one time formatting computation to save big on the searching piece.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
Sub add_column_binary_vlook(sheet_name_from As String, col_from As Integer, sheet_to As String)

'   set range  - the range to be the range in the vlookup
    Dim first_range As Range
    Set first_range = set_range(sheet_name_from, col_from)

'   set range - the range in the second sheet of the first column
    Dim second_range As Range
    Set second_range = set_range(sheet_to, 1)

'   find last column
    Dim last_col As Integer
    last_col = Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

'   set last col formula range
    Dim last_range As Range
    Set last_range = set_range(sheet_to, last_col + 1)


    Dim rows1 As Long
    rows1 = first_range.Cells(rows.Count, col_from).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' grab the length of the range on the first sheet

    Dim rows2 As Long
    rows2 = second_range.Cells(rows.Count, col_from).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' grab the length of the range on the second sheet

    With Worksheets(sheet_to)

        last_range.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(MID(RC[-16],10,24)," _
            & sheet_name_from & "!R2C" & col_from & ":R" & rows1 & "C" & col_from & ",1,FALSE)),0,1)"

    End With

'   label last column
    Worksheets(sheet_to).Cells(1, last_col + 1).Value = "Invited = 1"

End Sub
```